# reference for poisson equation on unbounded domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, regularity-theory-of-pdes, poissons-equation

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be some unbounded exterior domain, with $C^{\infty}$ smooth boundary. Consider the Poisson equation with Neumann boundary condition
\begin{align}
&\Delta u = f     & \text{ in }\Omega\\
&\partial_{\nu}u = g &\text{ on }\partial\Omega\\
&u\to u_{\infty} &\text{ as }|\mathbf{x}|\to\infty
\end{align}
where $u_{\infty}$ is some constant. There is a lot of literature on the well posedness in the space of $C^{2}(\Omega)\cap C^1(\bar{\Omega})$ when
$f$ and $g$ are $C^0$.
I wonder if there is any reference that considers higher regularity? I suppose we should have well-posedness in the space $C^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})$, if $f,g$ are both $C^{\infty}$. Does anyone know any reference to the infitely smooth case?

Comment: Do you mean to consider spaces of weaker regularity? If you have very highly regular functions and have a theorem valid in a weak regularity setting, you can invoke those theorems.

Comment: No. I'm referring to classical solutions here. Strong regularity

Comment: What I meant is not the distinction between weak vs classical solutions, rather 'weak' as the adjective in the usual English sense ('weaker theorem', 'stronger theorem'). What I mean is $C^{\infty}\subset C^2$, so if the theorem holds in the $C^2$ case it trivially holds in the $C^{\infty}$ case.

Comment: The fact that the problem is posed in an exterior domain makes no difference to regularity of the solution because you can just take a small ball in $\Omega$ and apply standard regularity results there

Comment: I know this should be true... I'm just asking if people know any reference on this.